# Preg_match getting contents in div tags in div tags

Tags: php, curl, xampp, preg-match-all

I want to extract all contents of div tag with the class **viewContent** but the problem when I executing the my code the php stop when reach the first closing tag of div. What should I do guys?. I have my sample code below but still only the first div tags get. Thank you guys for helping me.

```
  preg_match_all('#<div class="viewContent"[^>]*>(.*?)</div[^>]*>#is', $content, $s);
    print_r($s);
```

[image: Here is the image of my code.]

Comment: Which is that language in content ?

Comment: @noob It looks Korean, but I could be wrong. Unless you meant HTML. `:P`

Comment: @Laurel: Mr. Wr ines seems to have found a solution already. I hope you saw my **deleted** solution and his comments on it.

Comment: @noob You realize I'm WAAAAAAY below the rep needed to see others' deleted posts?

Comment: @Laurel: There you go. I undeleted it for you to see. Will add +10 to your rep ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The lazy or greedy search is of little use here because it's bound to match `</div>` which is not corresponding to `<div class="viewContent">`. So the end comment can be of use here as it **logically** marks the end of desired division.

Using following regex only the contents of `<div class="viewControl">` can be obtained.

**Regex:** `<div class="viewContent"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div[^>]*>(?=<!--viewContent-->)`

**Explanation:**

- `<div class="viewContent"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div[^>]*>` This matches the division with lazy search.
- `(?=<!--viewContent-->)` This `positively looks ahead` for comment which marks **logically** the end of `<div>`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX8bO4/1)**

Comment: $divs = '{<div\s+class="viewContent"\s*>((?:(?:(?!<div[^>]*>|</div>).)++|<div[^>]*>(?1)</div>)*)</div>}si'
;
preg_match_all($divs, $ContentDescription, $ContentDiv);

Comment: @Wrines01: You want me to delete this post so that you can delete your question, since you no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the closing tag for the div you want ends with `<!--viewContent-->`, you can use:

`<div class="viewContent"[^>]*>(.*?)</div[^>]*><!--viewContent-->`

Otherwise, you might just want to use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPs built in DOMDocument class to parse the html of the page and use the DOMXPath class to extract the value of an HTML element with a certain HTML class:

```
<?php
$html = '';//HTML goes here
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$classname = "viewContent";
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$spanner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
foreach ($spanner as $entry) {
  echo $entry->nodeValue;
}
```